# How to Prevent User from Logging in Twice

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a website and I'd like to prevent the user from logging in twice. How would I do that?

Sorry for not being specific. I meant that I don't want to show the login page once the user has logged in. It looks like the answer about using the $_SESSION is the best option.

I'm using PHP by the way.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Are you trying to prevent the same credentials from being used by multiple IP addresses simultaneously?

Comment: How does one "log in twice"? You mean, once they log out they can't log back in? You mean you don't want to show the login page if they're already logged in? You mean you don't want 2 simultaneous logins from different computers or browsers? Can you possibly provide more context here?

Comment: That depends a lot on how they are logging in in the first place. The simple answer is that if you know someone is logged in (according to a login cookie, for example), then you can just not allow them to follow the login path again. But your question needs more detail about your goals and current approach to user management. As written, it looks like you are trying to get an answer for a term paper or something.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. I meant that I don't want to show the login page once the user has logged in. It looks like the answer about using the $_SESSION is the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use the session eg [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php). Store user info first on logon and then check if that is set and redirect him to some other page you like like profile, panel or even home page.

See the manual for more information:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Answer (score 0):

On your login page put a bit of logic that detects if they are logged in. If so, redirect them to their profile page or wherever else you want them to go.

Answer (score 0):

Im not exactly sure how you would do that, but you would have to restrict logins to 1 for every ip address.  Is that what you are asking?  Please be more clear about what you are trying to ask

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using?

I would create a cookie for the user or set a session if php, then you can just check if the session is set in the header of each page.

Answer (score 0):

Create two cookie one for logged in and other for redirection . use session to find the user login activity ..if user try's for the index.php redirect him to home.php or anyother page

Answer (score 0):

Yes use the isset session feature to check if the user is logged in. If they are logged in then use a header location redirect to redirect the user to whatever page you want them to view.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password'])){ 
header("Location: members.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do it with sessions using [DALMP - Database Abstraction Layer for MySQL using PHP](http://docs.dalmp.com/en/latest/sessions/Example.html)